# Session is not getting maintain in settings.php drupal 7

Tags: 7, sessions, configuration

I have Created one php file on root of drupal7 and access it using URL.I have one form in that file which has dropdown values and submit button. Now in settings.php i am getting those value in POST. Based on That post value i want to select DB for drupal. But it Throws error because session is not getting maintain.
This is my code in settings.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['year'];
if(!empty($_SESSION['data'])) {
  $databases = array (
    'default' =>
       array (
        'default' =>
          array (
            'database' => 'mydbname'.$_SESSION['data'],
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => '',
          ),
      ),
  );
}
else {
  header("Location: welcome.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start `session_start()` the second time, since Drupal is already started it.

So either remove it, or wrap it into the condition, e.g.:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Parsing input user variables is not a good idea, so it's better if filter it out, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['data'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'year', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

or better use [`db_escape_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_escape_table/7).

Answer (score 0):

Session records are stored in the database. Hence, it is simply impossible to select the database connection based on values stored in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Using session it is not possible so I did it using Cookie.

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['yr'])|| $_COOKIE['yr'] == '') {
          if (isset($_POST['year'])) {
            setcookie("yr", $_POST['year']);
            $_COOKIE['yr'] = $_POST['year'];
          } else {
            header('Location: welcome.php');exit;
          }
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['year'])) {
            setcookie("yr", $_POST['year']);
            $_COOKIE['yr'] = $_POST['year'];
        }
        $databases = array (
          'default' =>
          array (
            'default' =>
            array (
              'database' => 'db' . $_COOKIE['yr'],
              'username' => 'root',
              'password' => '',
              'host' => 'localhost',
              'port' => '',
              'driver' => 'mysql',
              'prefix' => '',
            ),
          ),
        )
;
```